# Filter Text in ExpandableListView using BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext, adapter, expandablelistview

I need your help :)
I have a EditText and below a ExpandableListView. I have used a BaseExpandableListAdapter with groups/child. I would like that when the user writes in the EditText the ExpandableListView shows only the group (item) with the text inserted.
I think that I have to create a filter.
Here there is a piece of my source code.Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance

```
         @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState
               setContentView(R.layout.main);
               et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);

               et.setSingleLine();  
               et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (et.getText().toString().equals(""))
                elv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            else
            {
                elv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

            elv=getExpandableListView();
            mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(fields_select,description);
            elv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
               ......
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it, I have implemented the interface Filterable in this way:

```
   class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements Filterable{
```

and then I have override the getfilter() method. In the end, I wrote a class that extends the Filter class.

```
   public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new MyFilter();
    return filter;
}

    private class MyFilter extends Filter{
```